# Debugger.paused event not being thrown in CDP

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am trying to pause all tab's execution using Chrome DevTools protocol. For that I iterate over all the tabs to get the CDP client for each tab and then send a request to pause JS on every tab. I see it resolve for some tabs properly but not all of them. Any reason this would be happening?

Code that I am using to pause and wait for paused event to get fired:

```
await client.send(`Debugger.enable`)
new Promise(resolve => {
  client.on(`Debugger.paused`, resolve)
  client.send(`Debugger.pause`),
})
```

Comment: `Promise.all` runs everything in parallel. So, some things may run/complete before your `client.on` is been registered.

Comment: Good catch @mwilson. I have updated the code (in question as well) but I am still seeing some tabs not getting resolved.

Comment: I ran some tests on my side and I think it might be because the pages aren't executing any JS code after the call to pause JS has been made. As soon as I go to those pages and cause them to render, the `paused` event is thrown and JS execution is paused. An example of this is playwright.dev which doesn't do any background processing and if that tab is in background then `paused` event is not received from this page.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Pavel Feldman on PlayWright slack:
You can only pause in JS upon a stack guard. So if there is no JS running, there is no pause. To pause just issue a Runtime.evaluate after you issue pause.

Code that works on all types of pages:

```
await client.send(`Debugger.enable`)
new Promise(resolve => {
  client.once(`Debugger.paused`, resolve)
  client.send(`Debugger.pause`)
  client.send(`Runtime.evaluate`, {expression: ``})
})
```